# Is it possible to test Next.js 13 API Route handlers?

Tags: next.js, jestjs, ts-jest, next.js13

Trying to test a very simple route with Jest:

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json({ success: true })
}
```

But when I call `await GET()` inside a test, I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: Request is not defined
>
> ```
> > 1 | import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'
>     | ^
> ```

I tried passing a request object into the handler and then mocking it with `node-mocks-http`, but the same error occurs.

How can these handlers be unit tested?

Answer (score 3):

Just spent hours on this. Solved using by adding [jest-environment-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-environment-node) test environment:

```
npm i -D jest-environment-node
```

Make sure `testEnvironment: "node"` in `jest.config.js` (instead of `js-dom` or `jest-environment-jsdom`).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have pages and APIs in my project. If I change this away from jsdom are my pages tests going to blow up?

Comment: @JamesBender You can opt into an environment per test with a comment at the top of the file as detailed [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string). You may be able to select environment based on file path or whatever other conditions using a [custom environment](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string) but I've not done this.

Answer (score 0):

I have same the issue

> ReferenceError: Response is not definedJest

and I resolved by:

> yarn install -D isomorphic-fetch

then import to your test file

> import 'isomorphic-fetch'

example :

```
...
import { checkAuthenticated } from '@api/is-authenticated';
import 'isomorphic-fetch';

jest.mock('@database/video.repo');

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Reuben Drummond's answer will do the trick if you're not testing any react components or dom elements. IF you are then try following this:

Make sure `jest-environment-node` and `jest-environment-jsdom` are installed:

```
npm i jest-environment-jsdom jest-environment-node -D
```

Ensure your Node version is 18.17.0 or higher:

```
node -v
```

In your `jest.config.ts` set the following:

```
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
```

Now to resolve the `ReferenceError: Request is not defined` error in your API route tests add the following above your route test files:

```
/**
 * @jest-environment node
 */
```

This will ensure those tests are running in the node environment instead of jsdom environment. You can read more about that [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironment-string)